# Windows Server: PHP Script unable to open and write file in Windows Server 2012

Tags: php, windows-server-2012, windows-server, php-5.5

Is my first time working with Windows server 2012 and I am having a hard time trying to get a PHP script working. I have a PHP script that opens a JSON file, write the file and close it. Everything runs well but when I try to open a file in 'writing' mode an error is generated.

Here is the line where it fails:

```
 $myfile = fopen("master.json", "r+") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

When I open the files using **"r"** it opens without any issues, but when I try to open the file using **"r+", "w", "w+", "a+", "x+" or "c+"** is "unable to open file".

The PHP version on my server is **5.5.112.0**.

***Is there any permission issue I should be aware of? Something that I am missing?***
Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: r = read, r+ = read/write. you probably don't have write permissions on the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user running the webserver should need access to the file folder to be able to create the file.
Can you create a file with global write permissions and then write to it?

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Yep, it is. Because of the rating system I can't comment. On others.